# using vectors of class type A in class B

Tags: c++, class, vector

I've created a class A and a Class B, and I'm trying to set a vector of type B in A, and a vector of type A in B:

**class A Header:**

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

#include "B.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class A {

public:
    vector<B> bvector; // here is the error
    A();
};

#endif /* A_H_ */
```

**class B header:**

```
#ifndef B_H_
#define B_H_
#include "A.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class B {
vector<A> aVector; //Here is the error

public:
    B();
};

#endif /* B_H_ */
```

But I get the following errors:

> "..\src/B.h:16:8: error: 'A' was not declared in this scope
>
> ..\src/B.h:16:9: error: template argument 1 is invalid
>
> ..\src/B.h:16:9: error: template argument 2 is invalid"

Which flips to `A.h` if I delete the bad line in B. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to have a forward declaration of one of them (but since you can do it for both, you should do it in both, and not `#include` either header at all).

Comment: @SethCarnegie Forward declaration only works with pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346/why-cant-a-forward-declaration-be-used-for-a-stdvector

Comment: @num3ric it works anywhere that an incomplete type will suffice, which includes the declaration of a `vector`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, you're right it works anywhere an incomplete type suffices, but `std::vector` requires a complete type. It's undefined behaviour to instantiate most standard library templates with incomplete types, see  [res.on.functions]/2

Comment: @JonathanWakely well that sucks.

Comment: The template might need to know the size of the object at instantiation, or might need to know if it is assignable, or has a noexcept move constructor, or any number of other things that require the type to be complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ive created a class A and a Class B, im trying to set a vector of type
>   B in A, and a vector of type A in B

You are creating a [circular dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) between your classes. This is generally a bad thing, particularly in C++.

The compiler, in order to compile A, needs to know the definition of B (#include "B.h"). Unfortunately the B header contains a reference to A class (here's the circular reference).
The compiler can't handle this situation, since A header is already included in the current TU (see include guards).

Despite the fact that often having circular references is a symptom of a bad design, you can eventually overcome the problem using forward declaration.
For example you could modify B this way:

```
#ifndef B_H_
#define B_H_

#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class A; //forward declaration of class A
class B {
vector<A*> aVector; //note that you must only use pointer to A now 

public:
    B();
};

#endif /* B_H_ */
```

Using a forward declaration basically tells the compiler that a type A will be defined somewhere else. The compiler can rely on this fact, but it does not know anything about A (particularly it ignores the size of A and its methods).
So inside B, if you have forward declared A, you can use only pointers to A classes (pointers have always the same size) and you can't call any methods of an A class from inside B.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is that you need to forward declare one of the two classes.  Unfortunately, forward declarations won't let you use the full type in the header - they'll only allow you to use a pointer to the type.  So even that wouldn't work in this case.

You can use the **PIMPL idiom (Pointer to IMPLementation)** (google that) to circumvent this issue.

The PIMPL idiom would basically have you create a third type.  Then your type B would hold a pointer to an implementation class that contained your vector of type A.  All operations of the vector that was supposed to be held in B would be forwarded to the new implementation class which actually held the Vector of A.

**For example:**

```
//Forward declare impl class.
class BImpl;

class B {
    private:
        BImpl* impl;

    public:
        void PrintVector() { impl->PrintVector(); }
};

class A {
    private:
        std::vector<B> vec;

    public:
        void PrintVector() { /* Do printing */ }
};

class BImpl {
    private:
        std::vector<A> vec;

    public:
        void PrintVector() { /* Do Printing */ }
};
```

I haven't included the constructor or population methods for those classes, but you should get the general idea :)

Comment: if i understand correctly, the solution is a bypass, and therefore i am doing something tht is wrong in c++?

Comment: So the compiler (preprocessor?) starts in A, includes B which itself has no include statement. It then processes BImpl, including A, but A has already been defined so nothing happens. Problem resolved. Correct?

Comment: @user1778406 - You're not doing anything wrong necessarily.  There are circumstances in which circular references are a fact of life.  They can sometimes indicate that you should rethink your design - it may be overly complex.  If you can design them out, great, otherwise, this is a good solution.  This is actually originally a solution to decouple implementation from declaration to simplify dependencies between compilation units when building, but it works for this fine as well.

Comment: @num3ric - Pretty much.  B can use BImpl because it only uses a pointer which is forward declared.  A can use B because B is defined first.  BImpl can use A because A is defined before BImpl.  You can split this between multiple files and it will work fine - I just did it all in one place for ease of demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependency.

`A.h` includes `B.h` which includes `A.h`, but the `A_H_` guard is already defined so the contents of `A.h` are skipped, so the contents of `B.h` are processed, which refers to `A` but it's not defined yet because you haven't processed anything in `A.h` except the `#define` and `#include` directives at the top of `A.h`