# Does std::map<K,V>::iterator instantiate std::map<K,V>?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, stdmap, std

I have this code, which works on GCC:

```
#include <map>

class Foo;
class Bar;

typedef std::map<Foo,Bar> MyMap;

MyMap::iterator i;

class Foo
{
    MyMap::iterator some_data;
};
```

The code as currently designed (which is unpleasantly circular yes I'm stuck with it) requires `map<Foo,Bar>::iterator` to be available to `Foo` and `Bar`.

It works because the GCC library implementation happens to not need to instantiate the map's key type in order to instantiate the iterator.

Is this guaranteed? The standard seems to be somewhat hands-off when it comes to defining the map iterator type. How portable is this code?

Comment: You may need the exact version of the standard you care about; earlier standards where pretty broad with requirements that every type passed be complete.  Later standards made it narrower.  I don't know if that reduction in requirements change included std map.

Comment: I'll take whatever the most current standard says.

Comment: `MyMap::iterator` requires `MyMap` (so `std::map<Foo,Bar>`) (to answer to title). Not sure about completeness requirement key/value of `std::map`.

Comment: `std::map` requires *complete types*. I would say that `::iterator` *should* too.

Comment: Related to [forward-declaration-of-objects-with-stl-containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898935/forward-declaration-of-objects-with-stl-containers)

Comment: @Jarod42 I'd say that answer answers this one.  If you cannot `std::map<Foo,Bar>` without a complete `Foo`, you cannot name `std::map<Foo,Bar>::iterator`

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Do you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38899440/458742) means my code is not standards-compliant?

Comment: `typedef std::map<Foo,Bar> MyMap;` is already illegal.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Why? No instantiation happens there.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin No *value* is instantiated, but the *type* is.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont We are talking about template instantiation here, and there is no template instantiated.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin You are right; 14.7.1  Implicit instantiation [temp.inst] both says I am wrong (that `map<A,B>` is an instantiation), and is far from easy to determine if `map<A,B>::interator` actually requires instantiating `map<A,B>`.  A Note: seems to imply it, but notes are non-normative.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yep, otherwise `<iosfwd>` would be useless.

Comment: I can't speak towards how legal this is, but if it turns out not be, I think it may be possible to achieve the same thing using the CRTP: `template<class T> struct WithMapData { std::map<T, Bar>::iterator some_data; }; class Foo : WithMapData<Foo> { /* inherit some_data */ };`

Comment: @alterigel I have no idea why you think that would change anything?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'm by no means an expert on the details of template instantiation, nor do I really understand why the CRTP works. I just thought it might offer a way to delay the need to use the iterator type until the `Foo` class is defined. I apologize if I'm just adding noise to the conversation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This results in undefined behavior.

In the declaration `MyMap::iterator i;`, `MyMap` is required to be a complete type, thus it is implicitly instantiated. However, `Foo` and `Bar` are not complete at this point of instantiation, so the behavior is undefined according to [[res.on.functions]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/res.on.functions#2):

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> - ...
> - if an incomplete type ([basic.types]) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component or evaluating a concept, unless specifically allowed for that component.

Answer (score 0):

You can side-step the entire question by considering the fact that `std::map` is a node-based container, so that its nodes containing elements have stable addresses. I.e. you can use a plain pointer instead of an iterator (as long as you don't need an iterator to pass into member functions of the `std::map`, of course):

```
class Foo
{
    std::pair<Foo const, Bar>* some_data;
};
```

Note that only *declarations* for `Foo`, `Bar` and `std::pair<>` are needed here to define member `some_data`.

If you use `boost::multi_index` (which is superior to `std` associative containers in many ways) then it has extremely useful functions `to_iterator` that takes a reference to the element and returns an iterator to it.

Comment: doesnt this just move the question to whether `std::pair` can be instantiated with an incomplete type?

Comment: @user463035818 `std::pair<>` is not instantiated in `std::pair<>*`. Just like you can declare and pass around `std::ostream&` by only including its forward declaration `#include <iosfwd>`.