# Is there a way to iterate over incomplete structs

Tags: c++, c++11, incomplete-type

I have code like this:

```
#include <vector>

struct pollfd; // incomplete struct, since i did not included <poll>

struct Status{
   // abstract representation of pollfd, epoll_event, kevent
   int fd;
   int status; // my own status representation
};

class iterator{
public:
    hidden_pointer_iterator(const pollfd *pos) : pos(pos){}

    bool operator !=(iterator const &other) const{
        return ! ( *this == other);
    }

    bool operator ==(iterator const &other) const;
    iterator &operator ++();
    Status operator *() const;

private:
    const pollfd *pos;
};

class PollSelector{
public:
    // ...
    iterator begin() const; // pull pointer to fds_.data()
    iterator end() const;   // pull pointer to fds_.data() + fds_.size()

private:
    std::vector<pollfd> fds_;
};
```

I was able to make it run, by implementing all specific operations in the CPP file.

My question is - is there more "standard" way to do this iterator?

## Update

My code compiles and works.

I am qurious if there are something in std that can do all this automatically, without so much coding.

Comment: I think you can make that work. For more details, check out [pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl).

Comment: Oh, it works as a charm. I even template-ize it. Point is am I reinventing a wheel?

Comment: Sort of, but I actually "had" to do the same a month ago. Have never had the idea to do something like that before :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't a forward declaration be used for a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346/why-cant-a-forward-declaration-be-used-for-a-stdvector) Please [note alternative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15382714/1387438) (not accepted).

Answer (score 0):

A bit off-topic, IMO, this code abstracts away the wrong thing.

You should rather have multiple implementations of your demultiplexer engine interface, one that uses `epoll`, another for `kevent`, etc.. Demultiplexer engine interface is the one that allows you to register callbacks for file descriptor events, timers, signals, cross-thread, etc..

On Linux, there may be little point to using anything else but `epoll`.

Comment: this is the way i did it already. iterator is to iterate over statuses. However I do not like C headers to leak and make namespace "dirty"