# Forward declaration of class in C++

Tags: c++

I want two classes to 'include' each other in their variables.

```cpp
#include <vector>

class Bar;

class Foo {
public:
    Bar b1;
};

class Bar {
public:
    std::vector<Foo> f1;
};
```

I get this error `error: field 'b1' has incomplete type 'Bar'` while trying to compile. What's going wrong?

Comment: Vector doesn't need declaration of templated class, since it has fixed size anyway, but plain `Bar b1` needs (see this as an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/15382714/3365922). Essentially you can forward declare `Foo`, then declare `Bar` and then declare `Foo` and everything will compile.

Comment: Related/dupe: [How to create two classes in C++ which use each other as data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964482/how-to-create-two-classes-in-c-which-use-each-other-as-data).

Comment: While I am always careful with my designs to avoid circluar dependencies, it is sometimes needed.  My solution to this is to basically replace the Bar member with a std::unique_ptr<Bar> with custom deleter.
This custom deleter allows us to postpone the definition of the destructor until after the full type of Bar is known. 

Live demo : https://godbolt.org/z/qvf5rcdKT

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ compiler doesn't know how large a `Bar` object is yet, so it can't be included in `Foo`. However, a *pointer* to `Bar` *is* a known size, so you can use that.

```
class Bar;

class Foo {
public:
    Bar *b1;
};
```

Comment: If a 2 structs/classes contained each other, both would be infinitely large right?

Comment: @user16217248 In theory yes, that is recursion without a stop, but that wouldn't compile

Answer (score 0):

When declaring this:

```cpp
class Bar;

class Foo {
public:
    Bar b1;
};
```

Think about it, `Foo` has no idea what `Bar` "looks" like, it just knows that `Bar` is a class, so what the sizeof `Bar` and therefore `Foo` should be?

On the other hand, when using a pointer, it doesn't need to know the size of the object, because the sizeof pointer is fixed and known, therefore you could do what @Chris proposed.

But since C++17, `std::vector` also accepts incomplete type so you could define this in the header:

bar.h

```cpp
#include <vector>

class Foo;

class Bar
{
public:
    std::vector<Foo> f1;
};
```

foo.h

```
#include "bar.h"
class Foo
{
public:
    Bar b1;
};
```

Then include both bar.h and foo.h in both .cpp file.

Comment: Something one should potentially be aware of: Only `std::vector`, `std::list` and `std::forward_list` are guaranteed to be usable like this with an incomplete type, and only since C++17. It may or may not work for other standard library containers.

Comment: @thedemons The 2nd code in your answer has undefined behavior before C++17. [Why does std::vector work with incomplete types in class definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975491/why-does-stdvector-work-with-incomplete-types-in-class-definitions).

Comment: @JasonLiam yes I should have clarified that.